# Integrating AngularJS with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

Due [This Article](http://kielczewski.eu/2013/04/integrating-angularjs-with-requirejs/) I try to create an application with **AngularJS** and **RequireJS**!
I can load angular library... create module and export it to external files! It's ok!
But the problem is I can't create configuration and controllers for my module both in main application file and external files!
Another issue is I can't load views and controllers in app.js via $routeProvider!!

(Sorry for grammer problems!)

***app.js:***

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "/angularjs/js",
    paths: {
        "angular": "libs/angular.min"
    },
    shim: {
        "angular": {
            exports: "angular"
        }
    }
});

define('app', ['angular'], function(angular){
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                controller: 'HomeCtrl'
                templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
            });
    });

    return app;
});

require(["app", "controllers/homeController"]);
```

***controllers/homeController.js:***

```
require(["app"], function(app) {
app.controller("HomeCtrl",
    function($scope) {
            $scope.message = "Hello World!";
        }
    );
});
```

***index.html:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Angular.js</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-main="js/" src="js/libs/require.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

***views/home.html:***

```
<div ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
<h1>{{messge}}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I would go out on a limb and say that "you're doing it wrong."  Your controller should be short, simple, and easy to unit test.  You can define in different file for organization and use tool like GruntJs, Bower, and Yeoman to merge and minify these files if you really need it to transmit fast.

Comment: tnx. I'm new on angular, It is not strange if I'm wrong ;) in fact I want to create a module and export it and use it in controllers and ... (like Node.js) do you know how can I create something like this ?

Comment: Well, Angular is not like nodejs.  You can't use module like in node unless you use angular on the server side (express/jade).  You want to look into how to create an angular directive.  Then look into angular service and factory.

Comment: @Aref take a look at my example this may help you http://goo.gl/xqYGlj it has jQuery along for the ride just for the heck of it since i created this a while back

Answer (score 1):

Here is [my version](https://github.com/shustariov-andrey/angularjs-requirejs) of your example. With a few changes it works fine.

It is better to bootstrap AngularJs application manually, when RequireJs.

I separated **app.js** file in two: **main.js** - with configuration of RequireJs and **app.js** - with AngularJs module declaration. Later, this module is used by **homeController** for declaration of controller. Then, the controller is **required** in **main.js** and the application is bootstrapping.

Answer (score 1):

I do the angular and requireJS integration placing NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP! flag and have separate files for my app config and routing like in:

```
require.config({    
    baseUrl: 'js/',

    paths: {        
        angular: '../lib/bower_components/angular/angular.min',
        angularRoute: '../lib/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min'
    },  

    shim: {     
        'angular': {
            'exports': 'angular'
        },
        'angularRoute':{
            'deps': ['angular']
        }
    },  
    priority: [
        'angular'
    ]
});

//https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap
window.name = 'NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP!';

require([
    'angular',
    'app',
    'routes'
], function(angular, app, routes) {
    'use strict';
    var $html = angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]);  
    angular.element().ready(function() {                
        angular.resumeBootstrap([app['name']]);
    });
});
```

app.js:

```
define([
    'angular',
    'filters',
    'services',
    'directives',
    'controllers',
    'animations',
    'angularRoute'
    ], function (angular) {
        'use strict';
        return angular.module('myapp', [
            'ngRoute',
            'ngCookies',
            'ngAnimate',
            'myapp.services',
            'myapp.directives',
            'myapp.filters',
            'myapp.controllers',
            'myapp.animations'
        ]);
});
```

and routes.js:

```
define(['angular', 'app'], function(angular, app) {
    'use strict';

    return app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {     
        $routeProvider.    
          when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
          }).
          when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
          }).
          otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
          });       
    }])
});
```

hope this helps in your scenario.